# Excel Add-In Tab not Showing on Ribbon

Tags: excel, vba, tabs, add-in, ribbon

I've developed an Excel add-in. This add-in has been used for one year without any major issue. However, recently, users have been reporting that the add-in's tab does not show up when Excel starts.

Since this issue was not happening before and it is now happening with old and new versions of this add-in, I believe this is caused by some Excel or Windows update.

What should I do to make sure the add-in tab will always show up when Excel starts?
What is causing this issue?

I honestly have no idea how to approach this problem, any sugestion?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has released a security update that causes not to open an untrusted file when Excel opens. There are two possible solutions for this:

I - Unblock the file

1- Right click the xlam file 
2- Click on properties 
3- Under General tab click unblock 
4- Click ok 
5- Open Excel (Add-in should open automatically)

II- Add file path to trusted places

1- Go to File->Options->Trust Center->Trust Center Settings-> Add New Place 
2- Add file location and click ok

PS.: Names may be slightly different since I am not using the english version of Excel